# Google search in the search box

Tags: feature-request

When I searched for "pane docked" using the search box, I got 3 answers. When I repeated the search in Google using "site:mathematica.stackexchange.com pane docked", I got 3 pages.

What would it take to have an option in the search box to use Google engine?

Comment: "What would it take to have an option in the search box to use Google engine?" — the chances of that happening are little to none. There are alternatives (such as directly searching in Google) and plugins such as [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-the-current-site/jliolpcnkmolaaecncdfeofombdekjcp/related) (for Chrome) that lets you search the current site via Google (essentially, saves you the trouble of typing `site:foo.com` each time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend trying to replace the site search with Google, even if you can get a userscript that does this.  There are a number of search flags that will work with the integrated search that will not work with Google.  You can search for specific tags with `[tagname]`, restrict the search to questions (`is:question`) or answers (`is:answer`), search within code fields (`code:`), search only accepted answers (`isaccepted:1`) etc.  See [How do I search?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for more.

Instead I suggest you make searching using Google more convenient.  rm -rf referenced a Chrome plugin for site searches.  You can also (in Firefox at least, but I believe similarly elsewhere) use "keywords" such that typing `mma mysearch` in the location bar will search the site for `mysearch`.  In `Firefox` this is done by creating a bookmark with the keyword `mma` and the URL:

```
http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:mathematica.stackexchange.com%20%s
```

Note the `%s`: this will be filled by e.g. `mysearch` as described above.  Multi-word searches are possible.